# get _id based on value from a collection for a array and insert in mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, api

Input:

```
[{"gradeName":1,"sectionName":"a","maximumStudents":12},{"gradeName":2,"sectionName":"b","maximumStudents":13}]
```

In mongodb how to get the _id of gradeName and sectionName from two collection and store in the third collection say mergeddetails

mergeddetails:

```
[{"grade_id":"60f819e04a9d43158cabad55","section_id":"60f819e04a9d43158cabad54","maximumStudents":12},{"grade_id":"60f819e04a9d43158cabad59","section_id":"60f819e04a9d43158cabad5b","maximumStudents":13}]
```

where grade_id is the _id of corresponding gradeName,section_id is the _id of corresponding sectionName
please help with with mongodb quire i am using nodejs to write the API

Comment: can you show the two collections sample data

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$lookup` for both the collections

```
db.student.aggregate([
  { $lookup: 
    { from: "grade", 
      localField: "gradeName", 
      foreignField: "grade", 
      as: "grade" 
    } 
  }, 
  {$lookup: 
    { from: "section", 
      localField: "sectionName", 
      foreignField: "section", 
      as: "section" 
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$grade" },
  { $unwind: "$section" }, 
  {$project:
    {
      _id:0,
      "grade_id":"$grade._id",
      "section_id":"$section._id",
      maxStudent:1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: db.student is the final merged array is it

Comment: Please say db.student where is that collection to be created

Comment: `db.student` is the input collection `[{"gradeName":1,"sectionName":"a","maximumStudents":12},{"gradeName":2,"sectionName":"b","maximumStudents":13}]`